# Complex numbers/Calculate area of the triangle

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help solving thi task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is:

Complex numbers $a = 2019 + 2020i$,$ b = 2019−2018i$ and $c = λi$ in a complex plane they determine the vertices
triangle. Calculate the area of ​​this triangle depending on the parameter λ ∈ R.

I tried to find the distance between the complex numbers a and b, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Draw a diagram and use $\frac{1}{2}bh$.

Comment: All you really need is the basic formula: if $z = x + iy,~$ and $w = u + iv,~$ then
the distance between $z$ and $w$, which is usually expressed as $|z - w|~$ can be
computed as $\sqrt{(x-u)^2 + (y-v)^2}$.  Two things to note: (1) This formula is
identical to the formula you would have in $\mathbb{R^2}$ for computing (for example)
the distance between points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2).$ (2) In $\mathbb{C}$, the
*norm* of $z$ which represents its distance from the origin is 
expressed as $|z| = \sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

You may do it by finding the array
$A=\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \\ x_3 & y_3 \\ x_1 & y_1\end{vmatrix}.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

The segment joining $a$ and $b$ is **vertical** because real parts are equal. The distance is $$|b-a|=|(2020+2018)i|=2\times2019$$
The point $c$ lies on imaginary axis, which is also **vertical**. Therefore, the distance from $c$ to the side joining $a$ and $b$ is independent of $\lambda$ and equals $$|\Re(c)-\Re(a)|=|\Re(c)-\Re(b)|=2019$$

Answer (score 1):

You can think of these as points in the xy-plane, a= (2019, 2020), b= (2019, -2018).  Since they have the same "x" component, a and b lie on the same vertical line and the distance between them is 2020- (-2018)= 2020+ 2018= 4038.  $c=\lambda i$ would be (0, 1).  The distance from a to c is $\sqrt{(2019- 0)^2+ (2020-1)^2}= 2019\sqrt{2}$.  The distance from b to c is $\sqrt{(2019- 0)^2+ (-2018- 1)^2}= 2019\sqrt{2}$ also.

I presume you want to calculate those distances because you want to use the formula $A= \sqrt{s(s- a)(s- b)(s- b)}$ where a, b, and c are the lengths of the three sides and s is the "semi=perimeter", half the distance around the triangle, $\frac{1}{2}(a+ b+ c)$. So a+ b+ c= $4038+  4038\sqrt{2}$ and $s= 2019(1+ \sqrt{2}/2)$.

The area is $\sqrt{2(4038)(2019)^3(1+ \sqrt{2}/2)}= \sqrt{(4038)(2019)^3(2+ \sqrt{2})}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of these as points in the xy-plane, a= (2019, 2020), b= (2019, -2018).  Since they have the same "x" component, a and b lie on the same vertical line and the distance between them is 2020- (-2018)= 2020+ 2018= 4038.  $c=\lambda i$ would be (0, 1).  The distance from a to c is $\sqrt{(2019- 0)^2+ (2020-1)^2}= 2019\sqrt{2}$.  The distance from b to c is $\sqrt{(2019- 0)^2+ (-2018- 1)^2}= 2019\sqrt{2}$ also.

I presume you want to calculate those distances because you want to use the formula $A= \sqrt{s(s- a)(s- b)(s- b)}$ where a, b, and c are the lengths of the three sides and s is the "semi=perimeter", half the distance around the triangle, $\frac{1}{2}(a+ b+ c)$. So a+ b+ c= $4038+  4038\sqrt{2}$ and $s= 2019(1+ \sqrt{2}/2)$.

The area is $\sqrt{(4038)(2019)^3(2+ \sqrt{2})}$.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here depend on using Cartesian coordinates. Since we're in the complex plane we should use complex methods. As shown in Zwikker, C. (1968), The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications, Dover Press, the area of the triangle is given simply by

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\{z_1 z_2^*\}$$

where $z_1 \ \&\  z_2$ are 'vectors' from the same point. In your case we can choose $z_1=a-c \ \&\  z_2=b-c$. Then we have

$$z_1=2019+2020i-\lambda i\\
z_2=2019-2020i-\lambda i\\
z_2^*=2019+2020i+\lambda i\\
z_1 z_2^*=(z_1=2019+2020i-\lambda i)(2019+2020i+\lambda i)\\
A=\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\{z_1 z_2^*\}=2019*2020
$$

I have verified this result numerically for arbitrary values of $\lambda$.